# Understanding fleet composition

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

After I board a ship or force one to surrender, I'm given an option of adding that ship to my fleet. What are the effects of various fleet configurations? WIll my ship move at the speed of the slowest ship in the fleet? Will the ships help me in battle somehow? Do I need to worry about maintenance or something like that? Which ships make the best escorts for my flagship?

Answer (score 4):

> What are the effects of various fleet configurations?

Different crew size and different cargo capacity.

> WIll my ship move at the speed of the slowest ship in the fleet?

No, your ships will try to hold V-formation, but if they are slow they will be left behind (and you will see a sign "Wait for me!" next to them).

> Will the ships help me in battle somehow?

No, only your own flagship is involved in combat. Your other ships are assumed to be keeping their distance and don't appear in battle.

> Do I need to worry about maintenance or something like that?

Yes, each ship in your fleet requires a few men to sail it and food for them. If your crew is not enough for "Minimum Crew" requirement for each ship, all fleet becomes slow. Also, your fleet can run into reefs as well as your flagship can.

> Which ships make the best escorts for my flagship?

The best variant are ships with same speed or faster than your flagship.

[Source and more info](http://sidmeierspirates.wikia.com/wiki/Player%27s_Fleet)

Comment: So what happens when an escort goes too far away and displays "wait for me"? Won't the fleet slow down so it can catch up?

Comment: @kotekzot They will follow the flagship. Yes, formation will be stretch.

Comment: Pretty sure the formation doesn't stretch indefinitely - when a ship says "Wait for me", your flagship slows down for a short while to let them catch up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the effects of various fleet configurations?

While different crew size and cargo can help it also allows you to switch between ships if your flagship is badly damaged. The ships that are most useful in this is a ship in the frigate class. However Galleons are useful to but not in the sense of battle. Galleons should be used as bulk ships to carry extra cannons, food supplies, and extra crew members.

> Will my ship move at the speed of the slowest ship in the fleet?

Yes, however there is a way to avoid this. Right before a ship says "Wait for ME!" go to your fleet options and switch ships from your flagship to that ship. The lagging ship will be teleported to where your flagship was totally neglecting the waiting factor.

> Will the ships help me in battle somehow?

No. ships other than your flagship will be observing your battles. However you can always quick switch. This involves crippling a ship with say a war canoe then leaving the battle. After go to a ship with many crew to board. The ship you were previously attacking will be farther away but will not be able to port.

> Do I need to worry about maintenance or something like that?

Ships take damage in the following conditions:

1. Thunderstorms:Sails and a little hull damage
2. Crashing on rocks: Hull and a little sail damage
3. Cannon fire from ports: Hull AND Sail damage
4. Being shot at by a escort (not in combat):EXTREME HULL DAMAGE

> Which ships make the best escorts for my flagship?

This is primarily opinion based so I'll give my opinion. IN an 8 ship formation I like to have:

1. 1 Ship of the line (flagship)
2. 4 Galleons (used primarily for bulk goods and cannons)
3. 1 War canoe (used to cripple large galleons before boarding)
4. 2 ships of your Nation's FS

FS are free ships. In the beginning of the game you start out with a free ship in a port of your nation. If you get all the upgrades for that type of ship and sell it to that port in which you started you can get a x2 bonus cash.

Answer (score 2):

Because this seems to be primarily opinion based I'll voice my opinion.

> What are the effects of various fleet configurations?

There are three major fleet configurations that I know of. Two of them can make you money.

1. Trading Configuration - Made out of one Warship and the other seven treasure galleons or east indiamen.
2. War Configuration - Made out of 3 Warships and another galleon for excess food
3. Siege Configuration - This is just for going around and taking enemy cities. Very challenging to play as because of the need for a large crew and the unfortunate sieges which may give as little as 100 coins.

> Will my ship move at the speed of the slowest ship in the fleet?

In short yes. It is best to upgrade all your ships with cotton sails so that they can move faster. Also, hitting the edges of storms and clouds can give your fleet a boost.

> Do I need to worry about maintenance or something like that?

The factors listed by Young are correct. The only one he left out was:

1. Being shot by a pirate hunter - Pirate hunters can fire with extreme speeds and accuracy. A sloop can sink a fully upgraded Ship-of-the-Line in about 90 seconds.

> Which ships make the best escorts for my flagship?

You want at least a second ship exactly identical to your flagship. If you have to back out of a battle you can jump right back in with full swing. Personally I like to have 3 SotLs and a Mail Runner the strongest pinance class ship (25 cannons and 80 crew).